# How do I use gets/chomp in ruby to login in account without display strings in terminal?

Tags: ruby, io, rubygems, gmail, prompt

I'm using `gem gmail` in a project to login in a account using a terminal;
the OS is linux (debian whezzy).

The following is a example of running code:

```
user@linux:/home/user/project$ ruby --version
**ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [i686-linux]**

user@linux:/home/user/project$ ruby login.rb
===========
Gmail login
===========
please give your username (without @gmail.com) and password 
(they will not be show, so please type first, press RET, type password)
username: # waiting for username...
password: # waiting for password...
```

The Question is: using `gets.chomp`, the prompt display it username/password strings. I don't want this; I desire a functionality similar to UNIX-systems account login, i.e., prompt waiting for inputs, but without displaying them as user typing.

4 some refs, i put the used code:

```
def respond_to(&block)
  puts "==========="
  puts "Gmail login"
  puts "==========="

  puts "please give your username (without @gmail.com) and password (they will not be show, so please type first, press RET, type password)"

  Gmail.connect("#{gets.chomp}@gmail.com", "#{gets.chomp}") do |client|
    if client.logged_in?
      puts "\n#{client.username} sucessfully logged in!\n"
      yield(false, client)
    else
      true
    end
  end

end
```

I followed some tips in [zetcode](http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/io/), but without have rays of light.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few gems which can do what you want - one of them is [`password`](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/ruby-password/classes/Password.html):

> Ruby/Password is a collection of password handling routines for Ruby,
>   including an interface to CrackLib for the purposes of testing
>   password strength.
>
> ```
> require 'password'
>
>  # Define and check a password in code
>  pw = Password.new( "bigblackcat" )
>  pw.check
>
>  # Get and check a password from the keyboard
>  begin
>    password = Password.get( "New password: " )
>    password.check
>  rescue Password::WeakPassword => reason
>    puts reason
>    retry
>  end
> ```